# Field edit issue in a Salesforce screen flow exposed through a Force.com site

Tags: salesforce, field, edit, force.com, salesforce-flow

I am trying to let people edit a single Asset field through a flow which is exposed through a Force.com site.
Basically, the person receives a link to the site and should be able to go click through several Assets while filling in the data:
[image]

This works while running the flow directly and through a Visualforce page. But the site version does not display the text input despite the site guest user having the permissions to edit the field:
[image]

What could I be missing or doing wrong here? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a newbie on flows, the solution was right in front of me:
Using a number screen component instead and assign that value to the field afterwards ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️